# How do I prevent my touchpad from initialising?

Tags: touchpad

I run Ubuntu 16.04 on an HP Pavilion.  My touchpad is faulty and keeps making my cursor flick up and down.  I fix this by going into the terminal and typing "xinput set-prop 13 "Device Enabled" 0", but it is tedious to do this every time.  Is there a way please of changing the initialisation of my computer so that the touchpad does not get switched on in the first place?  I hardly ever use it.

Thanks for this reply, Bollix47.  To use your first solution I think I'd need to do this every time I use my computer, which I'm trying to avoid.  Your second solution looks better.  Would you please tell me how to write a bash file and to incorporate it in autostart?  I've never done this before.

Answer (score 0):

I've used gnome-tweak-tool to disable my touchpad.  Under Keyboard & Mouse click on the drop down menu next to Click Method and select None.

Another method I've used, that is dependent on having the synaptics driver installed (Synaptics TouchPad driver for X.Org server), is to create a simple bash file that you can run manually or automatically using autostart:

```
#!/bin/bash
synclient TouchpadOff=1
```